Representing a complex-valued function of a complex variable using Fourier Series
How do I represent a complex-valued function of a complex variable f(z) using Fourier Series?
Note I am not interested in representing the real and the imaginary parts separately as a fourier series since then we don't have guarantees on the differentiability of f(z).
Interested in the case when we can represent f(z) as a summation of cosine and sines of z. In which case differentiability is guaranteed.

You can relate the complex exponential form to the trigonometric form using Euler's formula:
$$
e^{inz} = \cos(nz) + i\sin(nz)
$$
Which allows an expression of complex Fourier series in terms of cosines and sines, but with complex coefficients shown as follows:
$$
f(z) = c_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (c_n e^{inz} + c_{-n} e^{-inz})
$$
$$
= c_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} ((c_n + c_{-n})\cos(nz) + i(c_n - c_{-n})\sin(nz))
$$
In this form, the coefficients $(c_n + c_{-n})$ and $i(c_n - c_{-n})$ are generally complex while maintaining the differentiability of the function.
$$
f(z) = c_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} ((c_n + c_{-n})\cos(nz) + i(c_n - c_{-n})\sin(nz))
$$
